# Python Enum: how to make enum member to behave like zero?

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

I have enum and I'd like some constants acts like 0. It's not the case by default (what is strange by itself). I have tried to bind **nonzero** method to enum member directly, but it's not called in if statment. What is going on!? And is there clear way to make FOO behave like 0?

```
from enum import Enum

class A(Enum):
    FOO = 0
    BAR = 1

if A.FOO: print 'foo!'
if A.BAR: print 'bar!'

setattr(A.FOO, '__nonzero__', (lambda self:False).__get__(A.FOO, A.FOO.__class__))

if A.FOO: print 'foo!'
print A.FOO.__nonzero__()
```

Output

```
foo!
bar!
foo!
False
```

Upd: for Python 2.7 zvone's solution looks like this and works fine:

```
from enum import Enum

class A(Enum):
    FOO = 0
    BAR = 1

    def __nonzero__(self): return self!=A.FOO

if A.FOO: print 'foo!'
if A.BAR: print 'bar!'
```

Comment: What about deriving from`IntEnum`?

Comment: Desired output?

Comment: Desired output:no 'foo!'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- there is no `enum` in Python 2.7 (the question is tagged as 2.7) - see [enum doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html); perhaps you are using the [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) backport?
- there is `enum` in Python 3.4 and later, but there is no `__nonzero__` there (Python 3 uses `__bool__` instead)
- The `__nonzero__`/`__bool__` method, if it existed, would have to be defined on the class and not on the instance

So, finally, there is a solution in Python 3:

```
class A(Enum):
    FOO = 0
    BAR = 1

    def __bool__(self):
         # only return False for A.FOO
         return self != A.FOO
```

And the solution for Python 2:

```
class A(Enum):
    FOO = 0
    BAR = 1

    def __nonzero__(self):
         # return boolean value of any A
         return bool(self._value_)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! I am using pyhton 2.7 and enum34 lib (?, installed by default with anaconda). The solution to implement __nonzero__ in class A (instead of __bool__) work fine!

Comment: @zvone:  Could you include the Python 2.7 part, and mention [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) and where to find it?

Comment: @EthanFurman I know nothing about `enum34`. If you feel that the answer can be improved, be my guest - the answer is editable for you as well ;)